# Reshaping Pandas Dataframe with Multiple Indices

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot, reshape, transpose

I need to reshape my dataframe so that it is wide instead of long, showing each date as column headings and two indices for state and variable name. I've tried using transpose(), melt(), stack(), unstack(), pivot() and set_index() unsuccessfully. Please advise!

The closest that I've come to the solutions is `forecasts.set_index(['State', 'Revenue', 'YoY_Change])` or `forecasts.set_index(['Date']).T` to transpose the date column, but neither are the correct solution.

My data looks like this:

[image]

And I need it to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `melt` followed by `pivot`:

```
(df.melt(['State','Date'])
   .pivot_table(index=['State', 'variable'], columns='Date', values='value', aggfunc='first')
)
```

Comment: I am getting an error that there are no numeric types to aggregate.

Comment: @JCM pass `agg_func='first'` to `pivot_table`.

Comment: Quang, can you help me understand how this solution works? I cannot understand why we melt state and date, and then pass in 'variable' and 'value' to pivot_table() when there are no variables called 'variable' and 'value'.

Comment: print `df.melt(['State','Date'])` to see how the data change. Basically it keeps `State` and `Date` as columns and stacks `Revenue`, `YoY_Change` in a new column named `variable` while putting the values in `value` column. Then next is `pivot_table`. You can read about `melt` and `pivot_table` from the document.